# Have you seen the symbol $D(g)$ with $g\in \mathcal O_X(X)$ where $X$ is a scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Have you seen the symbol $D(g)$ with $g\in \mathcal O_X(X)$ where $X$ is a scheme?

Comment: Yes. It’s the set of points where $g$ doesn’t vanish. So in the affine case you can think of it as the set of primes not containing $g$. It turns out that it’s an open subscheme of $X$.

Comment: Do you mean $D(g)=X_g$?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing.